# Cakephp ADmad CakePHP-HybridAuth Plugin threw Exception

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0, hybridauth

I am using ADmad/CakePHP-HybridAuth Plugin for Social auth. For this i followed the doc that given at https://github.com/ADmad/CakePHP-HybridAuth. I did same as it that done on doc but i am facing an Exception :-

**You must attach a listener for "HybridAuth.newUser" event which saves new user record and returns an user entity.**

Kindly help me to solve this problem.

**Example:**

UserModel:

```
    <?php
namespace Accounts\Model\Table;

use Accounts\Model\Entity\User;
use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validation;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;
use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Event\EventManager;
/**
 * Users Model
 *
 * @property \Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo $Roles
 */
class UsersTable extends Table
{


    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('users');
        $this->displayField('first_name');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsTo('Roles', [
            'foreignKey' => 'role_id',
            'joinType' => 'LEFT',
            'className' => 'Accounts.Roles',
        ]);

        $this->hasOne('Profiles', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'className' => 'Accounts.Profiles',
            'dependent' => true
        ]);

        $this->hasMany('ADmad/HybridAuth.SocialProfiles');
        EventManager::instance()->on('HybridAuth.newUser', [$this, 'createUser']);
    }

    public function createUser(Event $event) {
        // Entity representing record in social_profiles table
        $profile = $event->data()['profile'];

        $user = $this->newEntity(['email' => $profile->email]);
        $user = $this->save($user);

        if (!$user) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Unable to save new user');
        }

        return $user;
    }


    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->integer('id')
            ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

        return $validator;
    }


    public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
    {
        $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['email']));
        $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['username']));
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['role_id'], 'Roles'));
        return $rules;
    }

    public function beforeSave($event, $entity, $options){
        if($entity->first_name)
            $entity->slug = $this->createSlug($entity->first_name);
    }
}
```

**In App Controller :**

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'fields' => [
                        'username' => 'username',
                        'password' => 'password'
                    ]
                ],
                'ADmad/HybridAuth.HybridAuth'
            ],
            'loginAction' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'login',
                'plugin' => 'Accounts'
            ],
            'loginRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'login',
                'plugin' => 'Accounts'
            ],

        ]);
```

In UsersController:

```
public function login()
    {
        if( $this->Auth->user()){
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index', 'controller'=>'Users', 'plugin'=>'Accounts'));
        }else{

            if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->query('provider')) {

                $user = $this->Auth->identify();
                if ($user) {
                    $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
                }
                $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
            }
        }
    }
```

**Error Page**
[image]

Comment: Also start with the debugging hints that the error message provides, given that this is all about the users table, it's likely that there is a connection.

Answer (score -1):

The error is in this line

```
$User = $this-> new Entity (['email' => $profile-> email]);
```

You should be well

```
$User = $this-> newEntity ([ 'username' => 'valorunico', 'user' => $profile-> email, 'role_id' => 1]);
```

test to see ...

Comment: if you try to read the model you will observe that i am working in plugin named as Accounts so user model is in Accounts plugin but in Hybrid Auth Plugin it try to access user model from src->model->table instead of accounts->src->model->table so in short there was class name missing in HybridAuth model.